# Separate the Tap Event from the ImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am having a View where the TapGestureRecognizer is used. I am using the TapGestureRecognizer for the Single and double tap event. So far so good. Now I have added a ImageView on Top of the View , the image view frame is `imageView.frame=CGRectMake(50,290,205,100);`

Now wherever I am tapping the View , my @selectors being called. I want to skip the tap events only for the ImageView . How to do it ?

I tried using the

```
if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized)
{
    CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for the touch point ,

```
if(!CGRectContainsPoint(image.view.frame, point))
   {
      //Do you work here
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement this check

```
if(!CGRectContainsPoint(image.view.frame, point))
  {
     //Complete your Work
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this...I hope this will help you...

Whenever you tap on screen this delegate method will call..

in this method please check touch and gestureRecognizer will give some data regarding your tapping.....
Based on that you can proceed.....

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    NSLog(@"%@",touch.description);
    NSLog(@"%@",gestureRecognizer.description);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized)
{
    CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view];
    if(CGRectContainsPoint(imageView.frame,point)
    {
       //igonre
    }
    else
    {
      // continue
    }
}
```